# OpenGL access DepthComponent Texture in GLSL 400

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, depth

I'm trying to access a DepthComponent Texture in my GLSL Shader of version 400.

The program does a two pass rendering. In **the first pass** I render all the geometry and colors to a Framebuffer on which I have a ColorAttachment and DepthAttachment. The DepthAttachment is bound like this:

*(Note: I'm using C# with OpenTK, which is strongly typed, in my code examples.)*

```
GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment, TextureTarget.Texture2D, depthTexture.ID, 0);
```

The depth Texture has an internal pixel format of **DepthComponent32f**, pixel format of **DepthComponent** and **Float** as pixel type. All the other properties have default values.

**The second pass** renders the framebuffers color image onto the screen using the following shader:

```
#version 400
uniform sampler2D finalImage;
in vec2 texCoords;
out vec4 fragColor;
void main(){
    fragColor = vec4(texture2D(finalImage, texCoords.xy).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

But now I want to read the depth Texture(DepthComponent) instead of the color Texture(RGBA).

I tried a lot of things like disabling TextureCompareMode, using shadow2DSampler with `shadow2DProj(sampler, vec4(texCoords.xy, 0.0, 1.0))` or just `textureProj(sampler, vec3(texCoords.xy, 0.0))`. But it returns only 1 or 0, depends on which configuration I use.

To be sure that my depth Texture is ok, I've read the pixels back to a float array like this:

```
GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, depthTexture.Width, depthTexture.Height, PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float, float_array);
```

Everything seems to be correct, its showing me 1.0 for empty space and values between 0.99 and 1.0 for visible objects.

**Edit**
Here is a code example how my process looks like:

*Init code*

```
depthTexture= new GLEXTexture2D(width, height);
        depthTexture.TextureCompareMode = TextureCompareMode.None;
        depthTexture.CreateMutable(PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent32f, PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float);
***CreateMutable Function***
ReserveTextureID();
GLEX.glBeginTexture2D(ID);
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, pInternalFormat, width, height, 0, pFormat, pType, IntPtr.Zero);
ApplyOptions();
MarkReserved(true);
GLEX.glEndTexture2D();
```

*(Framebuffer attachment mentioned above)*

**Render pass 1**

```
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, drawBuffer.ID);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, depthTexture.Width, depthTexture.Height);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.StencilBufferBit);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.ClearColor(Color.Gray);
        GL.UseProgram(geometryPassShader.ID);
        geometry_shaderUniformMVPM.SetValueMat4(false, geometryImageMVMatrix * geometryImageProjMatrix);
        testRectangle.Render(PrimitiveType.QuadStrip);
        GL.UseProgram(0);
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);
```

**Render pass 2**

```
 GL.Viewport(0, 0, depthTexture.Width, depthTexture.Height);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.StencilBufferBit);
        GL.ClearColor(Color.White);
        GL.UseProgram(finalImageShader.ID);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);

        depthTexture.Bind();
        final_shaderUniformMVPM.SetValueMat4(false, finalImageMatrix);
        screenQuad.Render(PrimitiveType.Quads);
        GL.UseProgram(0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);
```

Comment: There is nothing special when reading from a depth texture compared to reading from a color texture. Please provide a minimal not working example since it is impossible to tell how your textures are bound etc.

Comment: @BDL added a code example of my process. Geometry shader is not included because its just a basic color shader and depth values are read correctly using ReadPixels.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you set the clear color *after*  you cleared the screen it will not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

A few hours later I found the solution. 
The Problem was the MinFilter. Like the khronos group said on [glTexParameter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml):

> The initial value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

I changed the MinFilter of my depth Texture to `GL_NEAREST` (where `GL_LINEAR` is also legal) and now the depth values in the GLSL shader are right (after linearization of course).

Additional Info:
There are some extensions for MagFilter like `LINEAR_DETAIL_ALPHA_SGIS`. I`ve tried some of these, the depth value correctness was not affected.

Comment: Please comment my answer if there is something wrong. If everything is fine, I´ll mark it as the answer.